# $A = \min(A_1, ..., A_n)$ where $A_i \sim Exp(\lambda_i)$ indep. find $P(A = A_k)$

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, order-statistics

I have calculated that $A \sim Exp(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i)$ but to find $P(A= A_k)$ is proving difficult as I am not sure how to calculate the distribution of $A-A_k$, perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Beware that e.g. $P(A=A_1)=P(A_1\leq\min(A_2,\dots,A_n))$ where $A_1$ and $\min(A_2,\dots,A_n)$ are independent and both have exponential distribution. So it boils down to finding $P(X\leq Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponentials with eventually distinct parameters.

Comment: @drhab ah I have to use the LTP

Comment: I don't exclude that but simply because I don't recognize abbreviation "LTP". Anyway, you can e.g. go for: $P(X\leq Y)=\int_0^{\infty}P(Y\geq x)f_X(x)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $B_n\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i)$ (here I am writing $B_n:=\min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}A_i$). This can be seen easily by induction as clearly the statement is true for $n=1$, and assuming it to be true for some positive integer $n$, then for $t>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(B_{n+1}> t) &= \mathbb P(B_n> t, A_{n+1}> t)\\
&= \mathbb P(B_n> t)\mathbb P(A_{n+1}> t)\\
&= e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i}e^{-\lambda_{n+1}}\\
&= e^{-\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i},
\end{align}
so that $B_{n+1}\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \lambda_i)$.

Now, given $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, we have
$$
\mathbb P(A=A_i) = \frac{\lambda_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j},
$$
as if $A_i\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda_i)$ and $B_i\sim\mathsf{Exp}(\lambda_j)$ are independent then
$$
\mathbb P(A_i\leqslant A_j) = \int_0^\infty\int_0^t \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i s}\lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j t}\ \mathsf ds\ \mathsf dt = \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\lambda_j}.
$$